# How to store user content while avoiding XSS vulnerabilities

Tags: php, mysql, sql, content-management-system, xss

I know similar questions have been asked but I am struggling to work out how to do it.

I am building a CMS, rather primitive right now, but it's as a learning exercise; in a production site, I would use an existing solution for sure.

I would like to take user input, which can be styled in a WYSIWYG editor. I would also like them to be able to insert images inline.

I understand I can store HTML in the database but how can I safely re-render this. I know there is no problem with the HTML being stored but it is my understanding that XSS become an issue if I were to just simply dump the user-generated code onto a layout template.

So the question put simply, is how can I store and safely rerender user content in cms? I am using Laravel and PHP. I also have a little knowledge of javascript if its required.

Comment: You need to add more details so it can be answered. There are tones of CMS'es on the market + millions of custom builds and you even doesn't mention what you use. This question is definitely opinion based and as it doesn't match Stackoverflow's requirements it will be closed.

Comment: @biesior with respect, I disagree that this question lacks enough detail. This questioner isn't asking whether TinyMCE is a good choice, but rather how to sanitize incoming input to defend against cybercreeps. The question has specific answers.

Comment: @O.Jones that good you're trying to help, however OP is not even asking about TinyMCE, but just WYSIWYG in general. This is very broad question and most probably will produce lot of opinion-based answers. Good behavior is writing questions that concerns on some real part of code, to answer "how to store users content to CMS" we can write whole books... Finally I'd sugest to get familiar with  [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @biesior I have not asked about any specific CMS or build as I am not using one. As I mentioned in the question above I am seeking to build a CMS. Therefore, I do not understand the premise of your comment? O. Jones is right when saying I was questioning how to protect against attacks. I feel you may have misunderstood my question? Happy to clarify it if it helps and you're able to provide a useful answer/suggestion to help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a CMS where you want to allow some tags but not others, then you want something like [HTML Purifier](https://htmlpurifier.org/). This will take HTML and run it against a whitelist and regenerate HTML that is safe to display back to the user.

Answer (score 1):

A good and cheap way to avoid cross-site scripting is to get your php program to entitize everything from your users' input before storing it in the database.  That is, you want to take this entry from a user

```
Hi there sucker! I just hacked your site.
<script>alert('You have been pwned!')</script>
```

and convert it to this before putting it into your database.

```
Hi there sucker! I just hacked your site.
&lt;script&gt;alert('You have been pwned!')&lt;/script&gt;
```

When you pass `&lt;` to a browser, it renders it as `<`, but it doesn't do anything else with it.

The [htmlentities(](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)) function can do this for you. And, php's [htmlspecialchars_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php) can reverse it if you need to. But you shouldn't reverse the operation unless you absolutely must do so, for example to load the document into an embedded editor for changes.

You can also choose to entitize user-furnished text after you retrieve it from your database and before you display it. If you get to the point where several people work on your code, you may want to do both for safety.

You can also render user-provided input inside `<pre>content</pre>` tags, which tells the brower to just render the text and do nothing else with it.

(Use right-click Inspect on this very page to see how Stack Overflow handles my malicious example.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @O. Jones. Thanks for highlighting the fact I could look on this page to see how stock overflow did it.  Could I then turn it back into an HTML tag eg. <img /> by using a regex to look for the htmlentity and replacing it for the tag again?

Comment: See this. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php  Avoid regular expressions for this sort of thing when you can use fully debugged language features ... lots of XSS vulnerabilities come from incompletely debugged sanitization functions like regexes.

Comment: Sorry, I'm sure I'm just missing something. If I use the function you've linked above, would this not change everything back into an HTML element as therefore the malicious code would still get injected? How would I use this to only convert say, <p> tags while handling <script> another way? Thanks again.

Comment: You asked how to turn the entitized data back to tags. I'm not sure why you would want to do that, but I suggested you avoid regexes and use built in language functions if you do it.

Comment: Thanks, @O. Jones appreciate your help.